# Using wireless networking with VMWare Workstation 6.5

Tags: wireless-networking, vmware-workstation

I am using [VMWare Workstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation) 6.5 and have installed Windows XP SP2 on it.
My main operating system is Windows 7.

When I am hard-wired, I can use the Internet inside VMware, but when I am wireless, I cannot use the Internet inside VMware.

I did some research and found that the network adapter should be on NAT instead of bridge. I tried that, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need to go in to the virtual network editor and choose which adapter is linked with which virtual network under Host Virtual Network Mappings.  It could be that your VM that is bridged is still trying to connect out through the unplugged wired network connection.  Have a look in there and you should be able to select VMNet0 to use the wireless connection instead of the wired.

EDIT: Right have loaded up VM Workstation at work and it is where I thought it was.  Go Start -> VMWare and load Virtual Network Editor.  This will bring up the config that I was talking about and the tab along the top "Host Virtual Network Mapping" may be of interest to you.

[image]

Comment: Tim: you mean some thing like this:? I took a screen shot of it 
http://i46.tinypic.com/10z036v.png
if not, can you please more specifically show me where should I go to check those settings?
thanks

Comment: I dont have VM Workstation at home but when I get to work on Monday I will try and get some screenshots for you.  The bit I am aiming for is not a VM specific setting but more governing the behaviour of the whole Virtual Network settings and DHCP controls etc.  On VmWare Server it is in the program folder in the start menu.  As I said I will get some screenshots for you on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

On my Vmware Workstation, I use bridged mode, and it doesn't matter if I use wired or wireless, it connects just fine and can switch between them.

Did you install / change / update the wireless card since the installation of Vmware Workstation?

It is possible that the VMware network driver is not bound to the network card - easiest thing you can do is a repair install of VMware workstation.

I am unsure how to help if it is more complicated than this as I have never encountered a problem with it.

Comment: Hi Wil,
no I have not install / change / update the wireless card .
I wish there was a way to find out if this is true or not: "It is possible that the VMware network driver is not bound to the network card"

Answer (score 1):

Let your network configuration remain on bridge.

When you switch from wired to wireless, sometimes it takes some time to change the link automatically.

If you disable the unplugged adapter it should work immediately.